# Installing Ubuntu over Windows - dangerous?

Tags: games, system-installation

I want to erase Windows 7 and install Ubuntu instead. I am not a pro user, so I have some questions:

a) Is it possible, that some devices don't work afterwards?

b) I have a little sister, and she will probably want to play games someday -
     how is the situation with games?

c) What are the "worst case scenarios" regarding installation? Like if I do smth wrong,
     can the PC become inoperable?

Regards

Comment: AU is not very suited for topic with more than 1 question in it.  1. unlikely; things to avoid: SIS graphics. 2. have a look at steam and chrome store for games upfront. 3. yes, it can happen (not often). Consider dual booting though! you can have both win7+ubuntu on the same system

Comment: sis is smth like nvidia, right?

Comment: Yes it is windows proprietary graphics; has not alot of support on other systems ;) If possible list your hardware related to 1 and 3 for an answer. Regarding 2: might be worth it listing a few games she plays or have a search for the game on google with "ubuntu" with it. Currently your question is rather vague for an accurate answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to not erase Windows 7 and install Ubuntu alongside. It's safer option in case something goes wrong, especially that you're not pro user.

A) The situation here is very similiar to Windows - Ubuntu comes with great amount of built-in drivers to plenty of different devices and if something is missing, you should get it online.

B) You can run Windows games on Ubuntu using Wine or PlayOnLinux + a lot of Steam games are available.

C) I think it's impossible to make PC inoperable by installing Ubuntu. Ubuntu installer is extremely user-friendly, so it's *almost* impossible to ruin your PC. Don't be afraid and give Ubuntu a try :)